Apps Script for Conference badge mail merge that changes border color based on text
I represent a school system trying to create a mail merge to make conference badges for our students for an event. We would like them to be color coded based on their first session. I can encode the hex color codes into the registration sheet so that the code populates into the badge template automatically using the Color tag.
Each badge will have a color border, I want to be able to customize that for each badge based on the hex code in the Color tag. The merge will create all the badges in one Google Slides doc, I would like to be able to then run a script to update the border colors on each badge before we print them.
Here is a copy of the Badge slide
I have included the hex code for the color of this border for reference. The 'border" is a pair of shapes with a white shape stacked on top of the color shape. It is only the colored shape in the background that I want to change.
My scripting skills are very limited so I have searched online and here for a tool or solution with no luck.
The closest I found in StackOverflow is this
I tried AI code and got this:

    function updateSlideColors() {
      // Get the active presentation
      var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
      
      // Loop through each slide
      var slides = presentation.getSlides();
      for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        var slide = slides[i];
        
        // Find the text box containing the color code
        var textBoxes = slide.getTextBoxes();
        var colorCode = null;
        for (var j = 0; j < textBoxes.length; j++) {
          var text = textBoxes[j].getText();
          if (text.length === 6 && text.match(/^#[0-9A-F]+$/i)) {
            colorCode = text;
            break; // Stop searching after finding the first valid code
          }
        }
        
        // Check if color code is found
        if (!colorCode) {
          console.warn("Slide " + (i + 1) + ": Color code not found in any text box.");
          continue;
        }
        
        // Convert hex code to RGB color object
        var red = parseInt(colorCode.substring(1, 3), 16);
        var green = parseInt(colorCode.substring(3, 5), 16);
        var blue = parseInt(colorCode.substring(5, 7), 16);
        var rgbColor = new RgbColor(red, green, blue);
        
        // Get all shapes on the slide
        var shapes = slide.getShapes();
        
        // Set fill color of the first shape (modify this to target specific shapes)
        var firstShape = shapes[0]; // Change this to target specific shapes by index or type
        firstShape.getFillProperties().setFillType(SolidFill.FILL_TYPE);
        firstShape.getFillProperties().setSolidFill(new SolidFill().setColor(rgbColor));
      }
    }

I do not need the script to pull the data from the sheet, the mail merge can get the color info into a text box on the slide. I would like to be able to pull that data on every sheet and set fill color and border color. I can make the border color white so that is doesn't have to be changed if that makes any real difference.
Thanks in advance for any ideas and suggestions you might have!

First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

When you look at the slide I copied over there is a color border. That is a rectangular slide shape and the fill color for the shape is making the border color. There is also a text box containing a hexadecimal color code. I want a script that can find the hex code from the text box and then use it to change the shape fill color. It needs to do this for multiple (>100) slides

Thank you for replying. I asked In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?. From your reply, I saw your provided Google Slide again. The 1st page and 2nd page are the sample input and output situations, respectively. And, you want to convert the 1st page to the 2nd page. Is my understanding correct?
